# Send back data changed on backend

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I made a POST method to send data from user input , recive it with Django views.py . Now i want to do some changes(ex. calculate return on invest) on that data and then send it again to display it on my page. Im stuck in it right now. I would really appreciate some help.

views.py

```
def valid(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        request_data = request.POST.getlist("invest")[0]
        investment = calculate_return_on_invest(request_data)
    
    return JsonResponse(investment, safe=False)
```

script.js

```
function ajaxdata(){
    let invest = document.getElementById('investment').value;
    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:'/valid/',
        data: {
                'invest': invest, 
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    
            },
        success: function (data){
            
            alert("works");
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("doesn't work")
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.
Simply added json object into JsonResponse
and then in succes function

```
 success: function (data){
            
            document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = data.response;
            alert("works");
        },
```